# Software for using Amazon S3 as backup service

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

What software do you recommend for using Amazon S3 as a placeholder for daily backups?

I need it to be fully automated, and easy to restore data.

Answer (score 14):

[JungleDisk](http://www.jungledisk.com/), now owned by Rackspace

Comment: I've been using JungleDisk for nearly 18 months now, it's brilliant!

Comment: JungleDisk has *really* gone downhill since Rackspace has bought it. There is virtually no support or sign of life and I would not be surprised if the product will be discontinued soon. I would definitely not recommend choosing JungleDisk as a backup solution at this point, until things are cleared up.

Answer (score 10):

[Duplicity](http://www.nongnu.org/duplicity/), is a close match for existing rsync solutions, using S3 as the target

Comment: +1 very reliable and open source tool - also GUI's for windows and ubuntu from 3rd parties that are well made. Unfortunately the GUI's for OS X are too buggy at the time of writing.

Answer (score 4):

[Deja Dup](https://launchpad.net/deja-dup) is a graphical frontend to duplicity that can target Amazon S3. It schedules regular backups, and offers incremental backups and encryption.

Comment: Note: Only for Ubuntu/linux.

Answer (score 2):

The best free script for S3 backup is [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/download).

For better options, you should use the svn version:

`svn co https://s3tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/s3tools/s3cmd/trunk/`

Comment: I'll 2nd this. A very flexible tool and easy to add to scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I use [S3Sync](http://s3sync.net/wiki). Works great!

Comment: I was most excited about s3sync, but found it buggy. For example, it transferred the same files over and over, instead of skipping them.

Comment: Seconded, I used s3sync extensively to push offline backups to s3 but found it to be unreliable, often failing mid backup due to poor error handling

Comment: Apparently s3sync is no longer being developed - according to http://s3sync.net/wiki